# Update year alone in date (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, update, date-format

When I checked one of my client's database, I found some mistakes which will make problems.
The problem is that the date is showing as `01-01-01` when I try to display it in the `dd-MM-yyyy` format the result is `01-01-0001`. How can I get rid of this problem. Is it possible to update the year alone in these dates.

I can find the dates with this problem by using this query

> `select from_date from date_table where length(extract(year from from_date))='2';`

Can I update this using the logic that

- Find the dates using the above query
- Update the year by checking the condition that `if year is between '00' and '13' prefix '20' with the year else prefix '19'`

How can I do this? Can I do it using Oracle query or should I write code for doing so?

Database is Oracle 11g R2 working in RHEL5.

Comment: if there are from_date values with a one digit year your query won't find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a number of days to from_date like this:

```
UPDATE table_date
SET from_date                              = from_date + 730487
WHERE LENGTH(extract(YEAR FROM from_date)) = '2'
AND from_date                             <= to_date('01/01/0014','dd/mm/yyyy')

UPDATE table_date
SET from_date                              = from_date + 693962
WHERE LENGTH(extract(YEAR FROM from_date)) = '2'
AND from_date                             > to_date('01/01/0014','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked fine for me. Can you please give an explanation?  Why is the to_date `01/01/0014`?

Comment: I guess that you have not date > 2014; so, if the from_date is > 2014 it is supposed to be a date from the previous century. So, the number of days to add is different. Note that, depending of the volum, you might have to iterate and commit every X rows.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommand always to use the appropriate datatypes, operators and functions and explicit conversion  and not to use string literals and string processing and implicit conversion.

Look at your statement

```
select from_date 
from date_table 
where length(extract(year from from_date))='2'
/
```

The return type of the length statement is clearly a number. So why do you compare it with a string literal? Something has to be converted implicitly. The number result of the length function to a string or the string literal `'2'` to a number. Do you know which one is converted? Do you know if there can any problems arise from this conversion? Is there a special reason why you take a string constant instead a number constant?

As far as I know the string constant will be converted to a number and I can't see any problems with this conversion. I also think that there is no special reason why you take a string constant instead of a number constant. But why bother about that questions?

Use a number literal and write

```
select from_date 
from date_table 
where length(extract(year from from_date))=2
/
```

I think you want to find all rows where from_date by the implicit conversion to a very early date and therefore is before 1st January 100. So why string processing? Use date processing and write

```
select from_date 
from date_table 
where from_date<to_date('0100-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
/
```

If there is an index on the from_date column this query may be able to use the index.

This query will also find rows with a from_date before `'0010-01-01 00:00:00'` and even dates before `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`. Also it can be easily adjusted to other timestamps. But if you want to explicitly use the year ( and you are sure that there are no dates before 0 B.C.) you can

```
select from_date 
from date_table 
where extract(year from from_date) between 0 and 99
/
```

If there is an index on the from_date column this query may not be able to use the index.

Adding 2000 years to a date can be done by adding `INTERVAL '2000' YEAR(4)`

```
UPDATE table_date
SET from_date  = from_date+INTERVAL '2000' YEAR(4)
WHERE to_date <to_date('0014-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
/


UPDATE table_date
SET from_date  = from_date+INTERVAL '1900' YEAR(4)
WHERE to_date >=to_date('0014-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
/
```

Because you started with string processing by inserting rows with the date represented as strings you can also make your correction using string processing. If you did not use a time part when inserting the rows you could/should omit the `HH24:MI:SS` format part in the following statements

```
UPDATE table_date
SET from_date  = to_date('20'||substring(to_char(from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),2),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE to_date <to_date('0014-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
/


UPDATE table_date
SET from_date  = to_date('19'||substring(to_char(from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),2),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE to_date >=to_date('0014-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
/
```